# How do I search for indices that satisfy condition in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have columns corresponding to a given day, month, and year in a numpy array called 'a' and I am comparing all three of these values to the columns of another array called 'b' which also correspond to day,month, and year to find the index of 'a' that is equal to 'b' so far I have tried:

```
a[:,3:6,1] == b[1,3:6]

array([[False,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True,  True],
   ..., 
   [False, False, False],
   [False, False, False],
   [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

which works fine but I need the row that corresponds to [True,True,True]
I've also tried:

```
np.where(a[:,3:6,1] == b[1,3:6], a[:,3:6,1])

ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
```

and

```
a[:,:,1].all(a[:,3:6,1] == b[1,3:6])

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

What is a quick and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.all()` along the last axis:

```
rows = np.where((a[:,3:6,1]==b[1,3:6]).all(axis=1))[0]
```

it will store in `rows` the indices where all the row contains `True` values.

Comment: Ahh so that's what I was missing. Makes sense now.